# Update the selected dates of date range picker for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I'm using the [date range picker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) for Twitter Bootstrap, by [Dan Grossman](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/).

When initialized, it's possible to set pre-defined values like startDate and endDate. Is it possible to update the values manually later on in a similar way?

What I want to do is to "load" the date range picker with filters I have saved, which includes a start and end date (not by defining pre-defined ranges). Just updating the field of the date range picker through jQuery won't update the actual selection of the calendar.

I guess I should do something like this when initializing the date range picker:

```
var reportrange = $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(),
DateRangePicker = reportrange.data('daterangepicker');
```

But then, how to use DateRangePicker to update the date range picker and calendar with new selected dates manually?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The latest version of this component provides methods for updating the start/end date:

```
$("#reportrange").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(startDate);
$("#reportrange").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(endDate);
```

You don't have to call the update methods yourself as these will handle all that.

Comment: There is a weird issue with this component, on selecting the startdate in range, it resets the enddate automatically, that's really bad, something i have seen for the first time. any comment?

Comment: can you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030630/remain-textbox-value-after-the-page-refreshed/61030820?noredirect=1#comment107973720_61030820

Answer (score 5):

I was on the right track. I could use DateRangePicker in the following way to update the dates:

```
DateRangePicker.startDate = moment(startDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10), DateRangePicker.format);
DateRangePicker.endDate = moment(endDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10), DateRangePicker.format);
DateRangePicker.updateView();
DateRangePicker.cb(DateRangePicker.startDate, DateRangePicker.endDate);
DateRangePicker.updateCalendars();
```

Comment: I had to also call DateRangePicker.updateInputText() to get the text input to update.

Answer (score 4):

additional information for Guillaume Lavoie's answer. This code worked for me:

```
orders = { order_sdate : "2015-01-01", order_edate : "2015-01-20" };

jQuery( "#order_date" ).val( order.order_sdate + " - " + order.order_edate );
jQuery( "#order_date" ).data('daterangepicker').startDate = moment( order.order_sdate, "YYYY-MM-DD" );
jQuery( "#order_date" ).data('daterangepicker').endDate = moment( order.order_edate, "YYYY-MM-DD" );
jQuery( "#order_date" ).data('daterangepicker').updateView();
jQuery( "#order_date" ).data('daterangepicker').updateCalendars();
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Your piece of code help me to find a way to set a new date range dynamically in the page.

One thing though. It seems that your way would update all DateRangePickers in the page (assuming you have more than one).

Also, the DateRangePicker prototype object might no be accessible in your page ( if plugin placed in an external JS file ).

Here is a way to update only the one linked to your jQuery selector.

```
// Init DateRangePicker
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({/* params */}),
...

// Update params dynamically after init.
// In this case, date format has been set to YYYY-MM-DD on init.
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.startDate = moment( '2013-12-24', datepicker.data().daterangepicker.format );
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.endDate = moment( '2013-12-25', datepicker.data().daterangepicker.format );
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.updateCalendars();
```

Comment: i'm getting this error in my console

Uncaught ReferenceError: daterangepicker is not defined

Answer (score -1):

This works for me :)

```
// Init DateRangePicker
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({/* params */}),
...

// Update params dynamically after init.
// In this case, date format has been set to YYYY-MM-DD on init.
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.startDate = moment( '2013-12-24', datepicker.data().daterangepicker.format );
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.endDate = moment( '2013-12-25', datepicker.data().daterangepicker.format );
$("#reportrange").data().daterangepicker.updateCalendars();
```